An application of Brouwer's fixed point theorem
Let $I=[0,1]$ and suppose that $f,g:I \longrightarrow I \times I$ are continuous functions such that $f(0)=(a,0), f(1)=(b,1), g(0)=(0,c)$ and $g(1)=(1,d)$. I want to prove that the paths intersect, that is, there exist $s,t \in I$ such that $f(t)=g(s)$. The hint of the book (An introduction to algebraic topology by J. Rotman) is to proceed by contradiction by constructing a continuous map $h: I \times I \longrightarrow I \times I$. As suggested by the book, suppose that the curves do not intersect. Let's write $f=(f_1,f_2)$ and $g=(g_1,g_2)$, then the natural choice for $h$ is $h(t,s):=\frac{1}{m(t,s)}(|f_1(t)-g_1(s)|,|f_2(t)-g_2(s)|)$ where $m(t,s):=max(|f_1(t)-g_1(s)|,|f_2(t)-g_2(s)|)$.
This map has the feature that $h(t,s)$ is either of the form $(1,\alpha)$ or of the form $(\beta,1)$ with $\alpha,\beta \in [0,1]$. In other words, we have $h(I\times I)=\{ (t,s) \in I\times I: t=1 \textrm{ or }s=1 \}$, i.e., $h$ maps the unit square into its boundary. This means the fixed points are either of the form $(t,1)$ or of the form $(1,s)$. If for instance $(t,1)=h(t,1)$, then this means $|f_2(t)-d| \geq 1-f_1(t)$ and $t=\frac{1-f_1(t)}{|f_2(t)-d|}$; however, so far I am unable to reach a contradiction from this point.
Can you give me a hint in order to complete my proof please? I feel like I am close but I am missing something.
In advance thank you very much for your help!

Your approach does not work. You want to show that $h$ does not have a fixed point which would be a contradiction to Brouwer's fixed point theorem.
Write $d_i(t,s) = \lvert f_i(t) - g_i(s) \rvert$, $i = 1,2$. By the assumption that $f$ and $g$ do no intersect, $m(t,s) = \max(d_1(t,s), d_2(t,s)) > 0$ for all $(t,s)$ (which shows that $h$ is well-defined).
Now consider the case $b = d < 1$ (which is of course allowed). Then $d_1(1,1) = \lvert b - 1\rvert = \lvert 1 - d \rvert = d_2(1,1)$. Thus $m(1,1) = d_i(1,1)$ which proves that $(1,1)$ is a fixed point of $h$.
For a proof Rotman refers to

Maehara, Ryuji. "The Jordan curve theorem via the Brouwer fixed point theorem." The American Mathematical Monthly 91.10 (1984): 641-643.

Maehara works with paths defined on $J = [-1,1]$ and considers paths $f, g : J \to J \times J$ such that $f(-1) = (a,-1), f(1) = (b,1)$ and $g(-1) = (-1,c), g(1) = (1,d)$ with $a, b, c, d \in J$. Proving that $f$ and $g$ intersect is clearly equivalent to proving Rotman's variant.
Define
$$d_1(t,s) = g_1(s) - f_1(t), d_2(t,s) = f_2(t) - g_2(t),  m(t,s) = \max (\lvert d_1(t,s) \rvert, \lvert d_1(t,s) \rvert) .$$
Under the assumption that $f, g$ do not intersect, the map
$$h : J \times J \to J \times J, h(t,s) = \frac{1}{m(t,s)}(d_1(t,s),d_2(t,s))$$
is well-defined. This looks very similar to you approach, but it is actually different because we can prove that it does not have a fixed point. Working with the homeomorphism $h : I \to J, h(x) = 2x -1$, allows to reduce the Rotman situation to Maehara's, but the formulae get more complicated.
It is easy to see that $h(t,s) \in \partial (J \times J) = J \times \{-1,1\} \cup \{-1,1\}\times J$. Now assume $h$ has a fixed point $(t_0,s_0)$. We must have $(t_0,s_0) \in \partial (J \times J)$, i,e. $t_0 = \pm 1$ or $s_0 = \pm 1$.
Let us consider the case $t_0 = -1$; the other cases can be treated similarly.
We have $\dfrac{d_1(-1,s_0)}{m(-1,s_0)} = -1$. But $d_1(-1,s_0) = g_1(s_0) + 1 \ge 0$, thus $\dfrac{d_1(-1,s_0)}{m(-1,s_0)} \ge 0$, a contradiction.
You see that the essential point in this proof is that $d_1(s,t)$ has a sign.
Remark. Your question has been asked before, but the answer has a different approach.

You're totally right. My approach does not work, I thought it would since Rotman suggested a map $h:I\times I \longrightarrow I \times I$ rather than a map defined on $J \times J$, where $J$ is as in your answer. Maybe he had in mind the homeomorphism you mention in your answer. Anyway, thank you very much for your help! :)

I doubt that the answer to the linked question  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266443/rotman-introduction-to-algebraic-topology-question-0-5 is correct.
